# What's the explanation for those shivers/shudders that happen at random times?

Tags: neuroscience

They happen at any time, presenting as a sudden urge to shiver/shudder all at once. It originates in the neck and shoulders, feels like instant gooosebumps then out of total reflex shoulders roll back and neck cringes. Happens every couple of months and comes out of nowhere, then gone without a trace.

I have read about myoclonic jerks but this doesn't sound the same.

Where do these impulses come from and what's the physiological explanation?

Comment: You should remove all personal references (and the line about ghosts). Everyone experiences these random shivers so you can edit your question to make it general. Also, we would highly appreciate if you can add some of your own research on this question.

Comment: Nice question, I'm curious too. Lets see what answer do you get. ;)

Answer (score -1):

It is just like a muscle spasm but generated from your nervous system. If the problem persist you are lacking in a certain vitamin that your body needs to function correctly.